# BitmapFactory.decodeResource return null in Emulator API level 5

Tags: android

I have this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
}
```

It works fine in Android Emulator Level 6 but not work in Emulator level 5, not depend on level of library was added in my project.
In Emulator level 5, BitmapFactory.decodeResource return null.

How to fix it. Plz help me.

Comment: its working well in API 5. check your drawable resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Create a `drawable` folder inside `res` folder and keep your `icon.png` image.

```
res/drawable/icon.png
```

And then you can try the above code.

Comment: Thanks. This gave me some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you call `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` with three parameters. create third parameter with this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds =false;
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon, options);
```